# How to scrape elements of Whatsapp web using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

Let me brief the problem, I wanted to scrape my own whats-app web data for my experience in scraping.
Unfortunately, whats-app web limits its elements to 12 or 10 elements at a time, I am not familiar with JavaScript, so **How can i get all the required elements bypassing the limits whats-app had made**

Thank you in advance for your help

MY code:

```
def __init__(self):
    #self.cookies = []
    chrome_options = Options()    #for now dont do --headless
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Unknown\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)    # so, browser keeps open dont close

    chrome_path = which('chromedriver')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, options=chrome_options)
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

    driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")
    time.sleep(10)
    recentList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_2wP_Y']")
    print('\n\n RECENT LIST\n\n')
    print(recentList)
    #self.html = driver.page_source

def parse(self, response):
    pass
    #resp = Selector(text=self.html)
```

Comment: just as you would manually... you'd generate those same actions using Selenium.  (clicks, waits, etc...)

Comment: well, i can, but, i can only click on every element using selenium, if all the elements are shown, which whatsapp web does not shows due to its limits, any other way to just get all the elements that i require and could bypass the limits?

Comment: Please share some code. If this is a design or architecture related question then chances of getting a answer are better if you ask in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. Happy coding!

Comment: Sure, Iam going to edit the whole question, sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: I have shared the code

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like `div[@class='_2wP_Y']` represents `div` for each *conversation*. And **WhatsApp** shows max of **16** of these classes in one viewport and you have to **scroll down** to get to newer conversations, but `div[@class='_2wP_Y']` count is always **16**! I would build an iterative logic where you collect `WebElement` for each **16** of these classes in to a `list`, scroll down event, and add next **16** into the previous list.

```
recentList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_2wP_Y']") 
for list in recentList :
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", list )
```

You can further extend the logic and add a function that just compared two `WebElement` and compare them for equality. If true, then that means you have exhausted the list of your conversations.

Comment: Thanks for your time,could you brief me about  the execute_script's parameters?

Comment: executes `JavaScript` in the current window

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [ActionChains](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) and `actions.move_to_element(desiredWebElement)`

Comment: Please could you explain the extend logic part of comparing two WebElement, code will help

Comment: by using your code, it wont scroll down to the most below, like it only scrolls one time